# How do I filter cells by a list of keywords, and import them into another sheet in a workbook?

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a list of customer feedback from a company's website.  We'd like to filter the data by store, so we can shout out the staff members or stores that are doing particularly well, and give them extra credit.  Obviously customers leaving feedback may mention the store location, the member of staff that they spoke to, or any other factor that they valued, so ideally I'd like the company to be able to add to a list of keywords that they can use for the filter.

The sheet that I've attached below is some test data that I've put together, in case the above isn't clear.

The closest I've got is using `=FILTER(All!A1:A10,ISNUMBER("Cardiff",All!A1:A10),"No Results")` - although I know this would have to be edited in detail every time another filter term needed to be added.  Also, for some reason, I'm returning the error "FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 10, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1." when I try it.

Would really appreciate any help anyone can give me - I'm completely confused, and making no progress!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1em4ix965Ej6ipevgfOfcfqtG-nOgT_9q5c4vdBHRyig/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Consider showing your _hand-entered_ expected results in the sample spreadsheet. Clearly identify where the expected results are.

Answer (score 0):

To find values in `Master!A1:A` that match the text string in cell `C1` *or* the text string in cell `C2`, use this:

`=iferror( filter( Master!A1:A, iferror(search(C1, Master!A1:A)) + iferror(search(C2, Master!A1:A)) ), "(no results)" )`

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks so much.  Annoying that the formula has to be updated each time I add another value (staff member arriving or similar) but definitely not the end of the world, and a lot better than the current method of doing it by hand!

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

Allows specifying search values in multiple cells

```
=IFNA(
   FILTER(A:A, 
     REGEXMATCH(A:A, "(?i)"&
     JOIN("|", QUERY(B:B, "WHERE B <> ''")))),
   "no match")
```

## Sample Data

Formula is in **`C2`**

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Reviews** | **Lookup Values** | **Formula** |
| **2** | New York location is great! | LOuiE | *`(Formula Here)`* New York location is great! |
| **3** | I was rude but joE put up with me! | Joe | I was rude but joE put up with me! |
| **4** | New Jersey location is OK! | York | The rep Louie was very helpful |
| **5** | The rep Louie was very helpful |  |  |

[image: screenshot of table showing formula]

## Explanation

1. Column A is FILTERED for rows that include the text strings located in Column B.
2. REGEXMATCH is used to perform the check and the regular expression is dynamically created as follows:

   1. **`(?i)`** is prepended to the expression to make it case insensitive.
   2. The expression is completed with a text string made up of substrings taken from an array returned by a QUERY which JOIN concatenates delimited by the regex **`|`** (or) operator.
3. IFNA handles errors when no match is found.